# If $\sum\limits_n \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X_n)}$ converges, then $\sum\limits_n (X_n - E[X_n])$ converges in $L^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I have seen in a paper to claim the following:

> If $\sum\limits_n \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X_n)} < \infty$, then $\sum\limits_n (X_n - E[X_n])$ converges in $L^2$, for any sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$.

As $\{X_n\}$ need not be independent, there will be covariance term, not understanding how is it possible ?

What about a.s. convergence?

Comment: what does mean $f(X)$ converges in $L^p$ when $X$ is a random variable ?  is it that $E(|f(X)|^p) = \int_{P} |f(x)|^p dx < \infty$ ? and if the $X_n$ are independent the implication is direct, while if they are 100% dependent $\sum_n X_n-E(X_n) = (X_1-E(X_1))  \sqrt{var(\sum_n (X_n-E(X_n)) / var(X_1)}$

Comment: @user1952009: how ? no guarantee that $\sum_n X_n$ converges

Comment: @Socha : I meant $\sum_n (X_n-E(X_n))$ you got me. so you have to prove that $var(\sum_n X_n−E(X_n))< \infty$, which if the $X_n$ are fully dependent can be written $\left(\sum_n \sqrt{var(X_n)}\right)^2$ (what a coincidence)

Comment: @user1952009: No, that is not the definition of $L^2$ convergence of a random series.

Comment: Removed a comment exchange that devolved towards insults. We have a "be nice" -policy. It is not enforced with 100% efficiency, but we do enforce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since

$$\begin{align*} \left\| \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k)) - \sum_{k=1}^m (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k)) \right\|_{L^2}^2 &= \left\| \sum_{k=m+1}^n (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k)) \right\|_{L^2}^2 \\ &= \sum_{k=m+1}^n \sum_{\ell=m+1}^n \text{cov}(X_k,X_{\ell}) \end{align*}$$

for all $n \geq m$, we find by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

$$\begin{align*} \left\| \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k)) - \sum_{k=1}^m (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k)) \right\|_{L^2}^2 &\leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n \sum_{\ell=m+1}^n \sqrt{\text{var}(X_k)} \sqrt{\text{var}(X_{\ell})} \\ &= \left( \sum_{k=m+1}^n \sqrt{\text{var}(X_k)} \right)^2. \end{align*}$$

By assumption, the sum at the right-hand side is a Cauchy sequence and therefore also the left-hand side is a Cauchy sequence. Now it follows from the completeness of $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mathbb{E}(X_k))$$

converges in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Another question: with this i will get a.s. convergence only for a subsequence. I am interested in finding sufficient condition (in terms of moments) so that $\sum_n (X_n - E[X_n])$ converges a.s.

Comment: @Sosha please open a new question.

Comment: I got the solution. Any standard maritingale convergence theorem for square integrable martingale solves it. Thanks again for the earlier solution.

Comment: @Sosha How do you know that it is a martingale? This is, in general, not correct if the random variables are not independent.

Comment: Actually, I did not write that in the original question. Individual $X_n$'s are $F_n$ measurable. Still I am writing this as a new question.

Comment: Plz check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644269/sufficient-unconditional-moment-condition-for-the-convergence-of-sum-n-x-n